# Does a colon go before or after parentheses?

Tags: grammar, american-english, punctuation, colons, parentheses

For example,

1. Shopping (At Whole Foods):
2. Shopping: (At Whole Foods)

Which one is right?

Comment: Pls answer ASAP if possible

Comment: I'd use the first version if what follows is a single shopping list (to be used at Whole Foods) and the second version if what follows is several shopping lists, one for Whole Foods and then others for other stores. (Also check what "ASAP" abbreviates.)

Comment: Isn't it as soon as possible? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, so your first comment asks us to answer as soon as possible if possible.